# Android and connecting to webpage with .http authentication

Tags: android, .htaccess, httpclient

I need to use httpclient to connect to a webpage (Apache) running PHP scripts which is protected with .htaccess authentication.

I've been reading questions and answers (in here and other places) for an hour now, and none of the sultions is working for me. Either the methods people are using in classes like Base64.java does not exist, or the parameters are wrong.

I'm connecting to normal (non-protected webpages like this):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", cDate));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
```

But this, naturally, doesn't help when the page is protected. So how can I, in the easiest way, pass my username and password to the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a Base64 here: http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/.

I usually do something like following for authentication:

```
            StringBuilder authentication = new StringBuilder().append("dogT4g").append(":").append("petTheDog5");
            String result = Base64.encodeBytes(authentication.toString().getBytes());
            httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + result);
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Warpzit: The second line gives this error:

The method encodeBytes(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64

Comment: @kakemonsteret Have you added Base64.jave file yet? It worked fine for me. http://sourceforge.net/projects/iharder/files/base64/2.3/Base64-v2.3.7.zip/download

Comment: @kakemonsteret you should add the class to your project and then import it where it is needed... It really works out of the box.

Comment: My bad (again) - I forgot to import the class :-)

Comment: @kakemonsteret hope you get it to work now then. Remember to mark as solved.